# How to debug WCF web service with Android client?

Tags: android, wcf, debugging, iis, publish

I have been developing WCF service and Android Application which can talk each other.In the development, when I do changes on web services I am publishing the service by right clicking the Web Project -> Publish Web Site each time.This is very annoying and time-consuming.

I am using visual studio 2013 .

Is it possible debugging without publishing the wcf service as a web site ? Is there any alternative way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes , you can debug the WCF services without publishing .Just right click on the .svc file from solution explorer then click 'View In browser' , then you will get a browser opened and with url like

*http://localhost:3006/ConsumerServices.svc*
then give this url where you call .Just put breakpoints where you wanted.

just for example , I have done using Angularjs..

```
                         $http({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'http://localhost:3006/ConsumerServices.svc/GetData',
                                data: DetailsJson,
                                headers:
                                        {
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                            'Content-Length': DetailsJson.length
                                        }
                            }).then(function (response) {
                                success(response);
                            }, function (errorresponse) {
                                error(errorresponse);
                            });
```

And also you can debug using google chrome's Advanced Rest Client(**chrome://apps/**)

And make some changes in the web.config file.as

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.But I am using webHttpBinding.Is it possible even so?

Comment: Ok I am trying now.What can you say about Just-In-Time debugger.Is it useful?